# In Kafka 2.X TopicAndPartition was deprecated

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka 2.X TopicAndPartition was deprecated how to fix while update Kafka from lower version to higher version

Answer (score 0):

The `kafka.common.TopicAndPartition` class is likely to have migrated to `org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition` in `2.x`. The constructor signature is same for both of them.

https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/common/TopicPartition.html